# Need to align 3 objects to centre of screen

Tags: html, css

I need to get the picture divs to always be centred on the page.
This is the structure at the moment.

**HOLDER DIV**
    (position: absolute; width: 100%; )
**2nd DIV**
(position: relative; width: 2272px; margin: 0 auto; )
**Picture Divs**
  (float: left)

This code works if the 2nd div is less than 1000px wide, but i need it to be 2272. Does anyone know how to fix this or get around it another way?

THanks

**EDIT**
Ok, This is a bit more of what i am trying to do. The site has a width of 960px. And then the div structure i mentioned above is going below the site, via z-index. And the 2 pictures need to be either side of the main site, one on the left and one on the right. So the width of 2272 is 2 pictures and the 960 padding where the site is. Here is a picture of the site.
http://cb.seddonmedia.com/RobertHillPhotography-Home-2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

try - http://jsfiddle.net/q5WwW/.

```
position: relative;
    left: 50%;
margin-left: -1136px;
```

Comment: Which div should i add this to?

Comment: middle one, the one with the width of 2272px.

Answer (score 0):

The css `margin: 0 auto;` only works if the selected element is less than the total width of its container.

Why do you need the 2nd div to be 2272px wide?

If you're trying to center-align a background image (my best guess as to what you're trying to do), you'd be better off applying the image via css and using `background-position: center center` to get it centered.

Here's some more info on the [css background property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background-properties).

Comment: I'm guessing he's trying to center the image? `margin:0 auto;` is an ideal way to center a div, or `align:center;` the div tag itself.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the post to explain what i need to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you are not constrained by a requirement to put the pictures behind the content via z index could you use a 3 column CSS layout to address this?

```
#top{
clear: both;
padding: 1px;
}
#left{
float: left;
width: 656px;
}
#right{
float: right;
width: 656px;
}
#middle{
padding: 0px 656px 0px 656px;
width: 960px;
}
#bottom{
clear: both;
}
```

The HTML would look like this in concept:

```
<body>
    <div id="top">TOP</div>
    <div id="left">LEFT</div>
    <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
    <div id="middle">MIDDLE</div>
    <div id="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
</body>
```

There are other ways to do 3 columns in CSS like:
[The Perfect 3 Column Liquid Layout (Percentage widths)](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm) 
or 
[3 Column CSS Layout: Fixed Width And Centered](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/3-column-layout-code/)

Answer (score -3):

Also, in html you can say:
    `<center> 
    <div></div>
    </center>`